# Click JButton and open a file.java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

[I have a jComoBox and JButton NewJDialog.java. How to pen A.java when i select "A" in JComboBox?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7rfM.png)

```
        if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "A"){
        A.java.setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to open a file you could use a Desktop Object like so.

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.open("your File object here");
```